# tinyMCE execCommand in ie8

Tags: tinymce

I tried following command of tinyMCE

```
tinyMCE.execCommand('mceRemoveControl',true, editor_id);
```

for removing control from destroyed editors.

Now when new editors are loaded via ajax call (in hidden form), all other input fields in the same page becomes disable in IE8. However if editors are loaded in visible form it works well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For tinymce 3.2.x, use the following to remove tinyMCE instance in IE8

```
tinyMCE.remove(editor); //editor is instance of tinymce editor and not editor id
```

This will fix "Permission Denied" error without disabling other input fields in the same page.